# Caching: refreshing external content

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

in a web project using myFaces 2.1.8, I use the following line of code in a composite component in order to include external content (located at the application server, outside of the webapp-folder):

```
<ui:include src="file:/#{someSingletonBean.externalContentDir}/#{cc.attrs.externalContentFilename}" />
```

The FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD context param is set to 2 hours.

Changes made to the external content files are however not refreshed until the server gets restarted.

Is there a way to populate these changes to myFaces without restarting the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug recently found and fixed in 2.2.4 that cause the problem. See [MYFACES-3890](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3890) for details.